# Formating bank account input only for display

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, input, format

I need to format a text input for bank number so that the numbers would look in this way:

> 11 2490 1111 0000 0000 2222 3333

The problem is I just want to show this formated (with spaces) for the user but to send it to the server without it (11249011110000000022223333). How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

This is what I've written using formatter.js library (http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/index.html):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var formatted = new Formatter(document.getElementById('bank_account-0'), {
        'pattern': '{{99}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}}',
        'persistent': false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not nice asking for people to do your work for you...

Comment: `.replace(/\s+/g, '')`? Still wonder why can't server do it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried to use formatter.js library this way:
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var formatted = new Formatter(document.getElementById('bank_account-0'), {
            'pattern': '{{99}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}}',
            'persistent': false
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: May you edit your question and show your effort?

Comment: Please don't assume I ask somebody to do my work for me :). I've tried in many ways with formatter.js. I don't need anybody to write code for me, I'm just looking for an example of a possible solution. Maybe any other library would be more appropriate or I can use regex combined with something, etc....

Comment: And it actually works fine with formatter.js but the problem is with the server-side validation which I unfortunately cannot change.

Comment: My apologies. I only made an assumption based on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to use simple PHP filter instead:

```
$element->addFilter('PregReplace', array( 'match' => '/\s/', 'replace' => '' ));
```

That works fine with `cleave.js` library on the frontend and meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bankAccount.value.replace(/ /g, '')`.

Code example:

```js
var bankAccount = document.getElementById('bank_account-0'),
    getNumber = document.getElementById('get_number');

new Formatter(bankAccount, {
  'pattern': '{{99}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}} {{9999}}',
  'persistent': false
});

getNumber.onclick = function() {
  var num = bankAccount.value.replace(/ /g, '');
  console.log(num);
}
```

```css
.input { width: 240px}
```

```html
<script src="//firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/javascripts/formatter.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input" id="bank_account-0" maxlength="26" pattern="\d*">
<button id="get_number">Get number</button>
```

Comment: That seemed to be a good solution for me, however I only managed to display the value in console (like you above). The value doesn't change the real value in the HTML attribute and sends it to the server in the unchanged version. I gues it's because of the formatting library I use that may have an eventListener that replaces it after all. Anyway, I switched from formatter.js to cleave.js now but no difference here.

Comment: Ok, finally I decided to use simple PHP filter instead ;)
    $element->addFilter('PregReplace', array(
        'match' => '/\s/',
        'replace' => ''
    ));
That works fine with cleave.js library on the frontend and meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider changing the value each time the input gets unfocused or pasted value into:

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourInputId');
a.onblur = function() { this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g, ''); };
```

Hint:
You might consider cutting the white-spaces on server side. This might be a part of server-side validation.

Comment: Nice solution that gives me an additional functionality, thanks! :) However I also need some event for a.onfocus then, when an user returns to edit the input text. Simply reverting this onblur function doesn't work here.

Comment: Ok, finally I decided to use simple PHP filter instead ;)
    $element->addFilter('PregReplace', array(
        'match' => '/\s/',
        'replace' => ''
    ));
That works fine with cleave.js library on the frontend and meet my requirements.